# Radeon hd 5700 monitor blank until connected HDMI device is started

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, reboot, amd-radeon

Have win7, radeon hd 5700. When both PC monitor and HDMI device (Onkyo 607) are connected to Radeon card, the monitor diplays boot info, "starting windows, etc" but goes blank when "log into windows" should appear. Monitor comes back (w normal screen) if Onkyo *and* TV are turned on, not before. Multiple monitors is disabled. Really crazy. Any help appreciated. Generally, Onkyo can pick up HDMI signal ok, so at least smth works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the video card detecting that there is or isn't an HDMI signal.  I'm dealing with a similar issue.  I've seen some hardware that sits between your hdmi output on the video card, and the input on the receiver that will trick the PC into thinking the TV is on, even if the receiver or TV is off.  Generally this is for the purpose of making sure the PC gets the correct EDID information.

[DVI EDID Adapters](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10110&cs_id=1011003&p_id=3048&seq=1&format=2)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem happened a lot when people tried using BNC > VGA converters without a box to give a signal. I believe any box (with power to initially program) that can remember the display ID should allow you to get around this problem.

I would check newegg or perhaps somewhere cheaper for the DVI flavor of a DisplayID box.

edit: completely missed the previous answer, much better put than mine!